# fixture 'driver_init' not found

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, fixtures

I am getting following error while running pytest using following code I'm unable to figure out what is wrong please find below code snippets.

I tried to map almost all but I still don't get it why code can't able to find driver_init. Please help me out

**confest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture(params=["chrome", "firefox"], scope='class')
def driver_init(request):
    if request.param == "chrome":
        web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    if request.param == "firefox":
        web_driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
    request.cls.driver = web_driver
    yield
    web_driver.close()
```

**testBase.py**

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_init")
class BaseIslandTest:
    pass
```

**testLogin.py**

```
class TestLogin(BaseIslandTest):
    def testSignupLinkVisible(self):
        self.loginPage = Login(self.driver)
        flag = self.loginPage.is_signup_link_exist()
        assert flag

    def testLoginPageTitle(self):
        self.loginPage = Login(self.driver)
        title = self.loginPage.get_title(testData.PAGE_TITLE)
        assert title == testData.PAGE_TITLE

    def testLogin(self):
        self.loginPage = Login(self.driver)
        self.loginPage.do_login(testData.USERNAME, testData.PASSWORDS)
```

**Login.py**

```
class Login(BasePage):
    USERNAME = (By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "form-group")][1]/input')
    PASSWORD = (By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "form-group")][2]/input')
    LOGIN_BTN = (By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class, "btn btn-primary btn-block")]')
    SIGNUP_LINK = (By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign up")

    """Constructor of the Page"""
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver.get(TestData.BASE_URL_PATH)

    """Page Action"""

    """Get Page title"""
    def get_login_page_title(self, title):
        return self.get_title(title)

    """Check for sign up page"""
    def is_signup_link_exist(self):
        return self.is_visible(self.SIGNUP_LINK)

    """Login into your account"""
    def do_login(self, username, password):
        self.do_send_keys(self.USERNAME, username)
        self.do_send_keys(self.PASSWORD, password)
        self.do_click(self.LOGIN_BTN)
```

**BasePage.py**

```
class BasePage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def do_click(self, by_locator):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)).click()

    def do_send_keys(self, by_locator, text):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)).send_keys(text)

    def get_element_text(self, by_locator):
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator))
        return element.text

    def is_visible(self, by_locator):
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator))
        return bool(element)

    def get_title(self, title):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.title_is(title))
        return self.driver.title
```

**Error**

```
    test setup failed
    file Project\Test\testLogin.py, line 18
      def testLogin(self):
       fixture 'driver_init' not found
       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, 
    capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, extra, include_metadata_in_junit_xml, 
    metadata, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, 
    record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, 
    tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

[image]

Comment: Please post error as a text, not an image.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: Sorry for that, but now I have added error as a text and photo both.